# How to select HTML Link element using xpath with multi criterias

Tags: html, xpath

In a page HTML, there are several HTML links whose names contains some sub nodes.

I want to retrieve only one of them; the following:

```
<a href='foo'>
   <b>Bar</b>
   <div style="height: 18px;">Garbo</div>
</a>
```

To target it, I want to precise with xpath: "**Bring me the link which contains both "Bar" as "Garbo", no matters if they are in separated sub nodes**".

I try this one, but after reading some articles about `contains` function, this line could never work:

```
//a[contains(text(),"Bar") and contains(text(),"Garbo")]
```

What fix could I make to fulfill my requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector you need to use is

```
//a[./*[contains(text(),"Bar")] and ./*[contains(text(),"Garbo")]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//a[descendant::text()[contains(., 'Bar')] 
  and 
    descendant::text()[contains(., 'Garbo')]
    ]
```

This selects any `a` element that has a descendant (not only a child) text node containing the string "Bar" and a descendant text node containing the string "Garbo" .

**This selects the wanted `a` element even it is the  following**:

```
<a href='foo'>
   <b><i>Bar</i></b>
   <div style="height: 18px;"><span>Garbo</span></div>
</a>
```